# Use angularjs to post JSON without a parameter name

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive

Currently I have a resource like so:

```
 return $resource(usersUrl, {}, {
        //The data model is loaded via a GET request to the app
        query: {method: 'GET', params: {}, isArray: false},
        putupdate: {method: 'PUT', params:{}}
    });
```

Now I would like to put some JSON that looks like:

```
{"providerid":"userpass","firstname":"t","lastname":"b","fullname":"t b","email":"emailaddress,"avatarurl":"http:/.....","passwordset":true}
```

Anyway as you can see it doesn't have a top level name, if I pass this information in as a parameter to the resource a name is appended to the json like:

```
myparam:{"providerid":"userpass","firstname":"t","lastname":"b","fullname":"t b","email":"emailaddress,"avatarurl":"http:/.....","passwordset":true}
```

Is there a away of preventing this from happening as the server side doesn't like it?

Thanks

Tom

Comment: I think that we will need more code to help... Try to reproduce this case at a fiddle :D

Answer (score 1):

From your question it sounds like you are trying to use `$resource` to post some arbitrary json data.  If this data is not a `Resource()` you should simply use `$http`.

```
$http.put(theUrl, theJsonData);
```

If it is actually a `Resource()` you can just call the method you declared when building your resource.

```
myResource.putupdate();
```

Comment: Thanks Mark, the data is user information in the webapp and so is picked up from a rest endpoint and processed, sounds resourceful enough to me, although i've only been using AngularJS for 24 hours, so I am probably wrong :) I'm a bit confused though, how does calling the method post the json back in the body, i've played with that and failed to pass anything back to the server.